# sort 2d numpy string array by keyword

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have numpy array loaded from csv like this:

```
array[['Blue', '1.1', '123', 'One'],
   ['Black', '5.7', '20', 'Two'],
   ['White', '2.0', '50', 'Three'],
   ['White', '0.3', '105', 'One']]
```

What I wanna do is to sort it **alphabetically** (1st cloumn) to be like this:

```
array[['Black', '5.7', '20', 'Two'],
   ['Blue', '1.1', '123', 'One'],
   ['White', '2.0', '50', 'Three'],
   ['White', '0.3', '105', 'One']]
```

And by **keyword** at 4th column:

```
array[['Blue', '1.1', '123', 'One'],
   ['White', '0.3', '105', 'One'],
   ['Black', '5.7', '20', 'Two'],
   ['White', '2.0', '50', 'Three']]
```

Is it even possible? `np.sort()` sorts it just fine but it shuffles all the values and sorts every single column independently.

Comment: What are the values of the 4th column, ordinals of numbers?

Comment: @DanielMesejo those are just strings. Let's just say it's Dog, Cat and Horse and I need it in certain order.

Comment: So why you said by number at 4th column?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I'm sorry. I meant by keyword.